# Echo output of hostname to /etc/hosts

Tags: 14.04, hostname

I am trying to create a dev host file like below -

```
$hostname
$ramratan-pc
$sudo echo "127.0.0.1 ramratan-pc" >> /etc/hosts
```

How I can put output of `hostname` in echo string?

*PS*

I do not want to create bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I think he wants $HOSTNAME instead of specifying the hostname.

Comment: edited the answer, just had to look up the variables

Comment: sudo echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts works for me. Thank you    @Videonauth